# how to bind a subject to a link and inject into a form

Tags: php, jquery

This is what i want to achieve:

A link which has a subject in it. When clicking on the link, you are directed to a form which has already filled in the subject of the link.

```
<!-- here should the subject in, lets say: reference 1 --> 
<a href="form.html">Link with subject</a>
```

The form:

```
<form action="">

<input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" /> <!-- the subject is already filled in from the link -->
<textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value=Send" />

</form>
```

The link and form are NOT on the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is tagged php why not use php for it?

```
<a href="form.html?subject=<?= urlencode('Your subject here') ?>">Link</a>
```

And in the form:

```
<form action="">
    <input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" value="<?= urldecode($_GET['subject']) ?>" />
</form>
```

**Warning:** This is not secure and you need to sanitize the subject variable first before showing it back to the user.

Comment: this works great! Have one more questiona bout this: in the value there is **<?=** . **<?php=** seems to give an error. Can someone explain me this?

Comment: **<?=** is shorthand for **<? echo** available from PHP 5.4.0 (before it required short_open_tag directive to be on). **<?php** requires whitespace after to properly start PHP script so **<?php=** would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged php, you can use a query string in the link:

```
<!-- here subject is in query string --> 
<a href="form.php?subject=Link+with+subject">Link with subject</a>
```

And php's `$_GET` superglobal to retrieve it:

```
<form action="">

<input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" value="<?php echo $_GET['subject'];?>" /> <!-- the subject is already filled in from the link -->
<textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value=Send" />

</form>
```